# I'm having problem adding new line in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

When adding the first line, it is done without problems, but when trying to add the second line, an error appears

> It must not be a negative value or outside the range

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)  `// التحقق من وجود صفوف قبل إضافة صف جديد`
{
    int nu = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;  `// الحصول على الفهرس الصحيح للصف الجديد`
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
    dataGridView1.Rows[nu].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;  `//  Here the problem`   
    dataGridView1.Rows[nu].Cells[6].Value = dt.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
    dataGridView1.Rows[nu].Cells[1].Value = dt.Tables[0].Rows[0][1];
    dataGridView1.Rows[nu].Cells[3].Value = 1; `// الكمية`
    dataGridView1.Rows[nu].Cells[2].Value = dt.Tables[0].Rows[0][3];
    dataGridView1.Rows[nu].Cells[7].Value = dt.Tables[0].Rows[0][2];
    MessageBox.Show("سطر جديد");
}
```

If it is like this

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
```

It redisplays the data in the same place, on the first line
To add a new line every time When not found the code in the datagridview

Comment: Try: `int nu = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;` Index starts at zero.

Comment: Poul Bak: In this case, it returns the value to 0 and writes it on the same line and does not add a new line

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have to decrease by 1 the index obtained using count (dataGridView1.Rows.Count).

Array index starts at 0.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work